# Full Calendar scheduler increasing height of event bars in timeline

Tags: css, fullcalendar, scheduler

I've been using Full Calendar Scheduler for a while now in order to create a calendar for a client, except the "events" are just job allocation times.

I've styled up the calendar itself to suit the client, but the actual event bars that appear on the calendar after the data has been fed through are only about half the height of the actual time slot. I'm aware that this is likely to be for the purpose of overlapping events in general, but this will never happen in this case, so is there a way of increasing the height of the event bar to 100% of the time slot? I've tried in the CSS but it never works.

This is in timeline view, for a week, going horizontally rather than vertically. I have attached a screenshot as an example.

[image]

EDIT: Code for calendar

JS:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    resourceAreaWidth: "20%",
    editable: true,
    aspectRatio: 2.5,
    scrollTime: '08:00',
    minTime: '08:00',
    maxTime: '22:00',
    firstDay: 1,
    header: {
        left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timelineDay,timelineWeek,timelineMonth'
    },
    customButtons: {

    },
    defaultView: 'timelineWeek',
    views: {
        timelineWeek: {
            type: 'timeline',
            slotWidth: 60,
            slotDuration: '02:00',
            duration: { days: 6 }
        }
    },
    slotLabelFormat: [
        'dddd D/M/YY',
        'h:mma'
    ],
    events: [
        { id: '1', resourceId: '1', start: '2016-10-24 08:00:00', end: '2016-10-24 10:00:00', title: 'TESTREF001', url: 'null' },
    ],
    resourceLabelText: 'Staff',
    resources: [
        { id: '1', title: 'John Doe' },
    ]
});
```

CSS:

```
.fc-widget-header > .fc-cell-content > .fc-cell-text {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.fc-widget-header > .fc-cell-content {
    background: #e4dbff;
}

.fc-time-area .fc-widget-header {
    background: #e4dbff !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}

.fc-unthemed th, .fc-unthemed td, .fc-unthemed thead, .fc-unthemed tbody, .fc-unthemed .fc-divider, .fc-unthemed .fc-row, .fc-unthemed .fc-content, .fc-unthemed .fc-popover, .fc-unthemed .fc-list-view, .fc-unthemed .fc-list-heading td {
    border-color: #AAA !important;
}

.fc-body .fc-resource-area .fc-cell-content, .fc-body .fc-resource-area .fc-widget-content > div {
    background: #f9f2c7;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.fc-widget-header > div > .fc-cell-content > .fc-cell-text {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
.fc-widget-header {
    background: #f9f2c7;
}

.fc-widget-content.fc-major {
    background: #fff2e7;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fc-resource-area .fc-scroller-canvas {
    background: #f9f2c7;
}
```

Comment: Add your full code please.

Comment: Have added JS and CSS now

Comment: Sorry but your full code very necessary

Comment: What else do you need? The JS controls the calendar, the CSS styles it. The only other code is an empty div with the id "calendar".

Comment: nothing happen, check out this fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/jfy0wry6/

Comment: Well you need the base script, but it's minified. I guess you could include it from the CDN. But the issue here is not the functionality but the styling. The calendar works fine.

Comment: Plus bear in mind the JS I gave you goes into a Twig file hence the variables used. You should look at the code before inserting into a jsfiddle. Replace it with actual data.

Comment: I know, but I'm need to see something to get your problem. I'm include the CDNs.

Comment: I have changed the JS so it's hard coded events and resources.